# php artisan cache clear PDOException could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, postgresql-10, macos-big-sur

When I run laravel command in terminal `php artisan cache:clear`, I got error `could not find driver (SQL: delete from "cache")` .

[image]

I have done some solution that I found like :

- uncomment extension pdo_pgsql in php.ini
- clear files in /storage/framework/cache directory
- clear config.php, packages.php and services.php files in /bootstrap/cache directory
- uninstall and install nginx, php and postgresql

None of them worked.

I migrate data using `php artisan` command is worked well. If I run `php artisan route:cache`, `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan view:clear`, they are also worked well. Only `php artisan cache:clear` command got problem.

For additional information, this happened after I update my OS to Big Sur (11.1) and these are the version I am using.

- nginx 1.19.6
- php 7.3.24
- postgresql 10.15
- laravel 5.5.45

Please help me.

Comment: check if laravel 5.5.45 is compatible with your PHP version and supported by artisan, it could be your OS update has upgraded your PHP version.

Comment: Sorry for mistyping. I am using PHP 7.3.24 and that not got updated after I updated OS. But, my Postgres got updated from 10.13 to 10.15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. PHP cause this problem. Actually mac has preinstalled PHP and this was what I use. This PHP got trouble if we upgrade OS to Big Sur (11.1).

I install PHP from homebrew. I use brew link to make homebrew PHP default. I also set the PATH variable. Restart my terminal and it works.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Linux os you should install PHP PDO extension and MySQL extension

```
apt-get install php-mysql
apt-get install php-pdo
```

if was not work that , you can install it with the following

```
apt-get install php-common
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am not using Linux. Hehe